# Do the Web Store Payments work still? Docs accurate?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There's no recent posts or activity, the documentation is ancient, and my efforts to add subscription payments just outputs this for a subscription purchase:

[image]

The query calls all seem to work, the payment box opens, but I'm thinking that maybe I'm chasing a deprecated API?  I'm not sure what's still active and what's not.  :(  I've tried in both debug mode and with a published (unlisted) app.

Answer (score 0):

You may check on this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145712/191211). Maybe your Google Account had Google Payments disabled for all users. Try enabling it and see if it works. You can also try deleting your card from your account and add it back again or try different browsers and delete caches.

This issue was also reported in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/pY_Rpt3P1eo) and suggested action is to [contact the support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/community_play?ec=apps,c2c_general,chat_general&cfsi=other_app&cfnti=escalationflow.c2c&cft=5&from=directurl&hl=en&visit_id=1-636100764011682718-713626821&rd=1) to fix the issue.